# Singleton service using IApplicationBuilder returning UserManager scoped service error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm a little confused, I'm registering a RabbitMQ listener in my .NET Core application and its returning a scoping error:

> An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Cannot consume scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[AuthService.Models.DbEntities.User]' from singleton 'AuthService.Services.RabbitMqListener'.

However, I'm not actually using the UserManager in my service. The consturctor only uses other singleton services:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<RabbitMqListener>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRabbitListener();
}

public static class ApplicationBuilderExtentions
{
    public static RabbitMqListener Listener { get; set; }

    public static IApplicationBuilder UseRabbitListener(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        Listener = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<RabbitMqListener>();

        var life = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IApplicationLifetime>();

        life.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStarted);

        life.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnStopping);

        return app;
    }

    private static void OnStarted()
    {
        Listener.Register();
    }

    private static void OnStopping()
    {
        Listener.Deregister();
    }
}
```

Constructor from my RabbitMQ Service:

```
public class RabbitMqListener
{
    private readonly IJWTFactory _jwtFactory;
    private readonly IConnection _mqConnection;
    private readonly IModel _channel;
    private readonly ILogger<RabbitMqListener> _logger;

    public RabbitMqListener(
            IJWTFactory jwtFactory,
            ILogger<RabbitMqListener> logger
        )
    {
        _jwtFactory = jwtFactory;
        _mqConnection = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" }.CreateConnection();
        _channel = _mqConnection.CreateModel();
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why the `UserManager` service is being used for my service that isn't using it?

Comment: `UserManager ` is used by `RabbitMqListener` or on its dependencies (or one of its dependencies' dependencies). Remove the `RabbitMqListener` constructor parameters one by one until the error stops. When the error stops, the last one you removed was the culprit.

Comment: @mjwills Ah, the JwtFactory uses the UserManager. I'll investigate the dependancy and see why this is all of a sudden a problem. I've not actually touched the services, but i did update the .NET Core package, I guess my service registration had scoping issues before the update.

Comment: @mjwills Turns out the JwtFactory had the UserManager registered but wasn't even using it. God knows why I did this. Thank you for the direction.